# abcde: What is an ~/.abcde.conf file to rip to multiple formats?

Tags: cd, cd-ripping, abcde

The 'canonical' abcde conf file section of the website at andrews-corner has been removed; what is a conf file that I can use now to rip my audio cds with abcde to multiple different formats *at the same time* under Ubuntu?

*Disclaimer: This is my web site and I am a former developer of abcde...*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Disclaimer: This my web site and I am a former developer of abcde...*

The web author of andrews-corner has moved to other areas of interest now but preserved here is an ~/.abcde.conf that will rip to 11 different audio formats *at the same time*:

```
# -----------------$HOME/.abcde.conf----------------- #
# 
#  A sample configuration file to convert music cds to 
#  MP3, Ogg Vorbis, FLAC, Musepack, AAC, WavPack, Opus,
#  Monkey's Audio (ape), True Audio, AC3 and mp2, 11 formats
#  at the same time! Using abcde version 2.7.2 release version.
# 
#   Acknowledgements to http://andrews-corner.org
# -------------------------------------------------- #

# Encode tracks immediately after reading. Saves disk space, gives
# better reading of 'scratchy' disks and better troubleshooting of
# encoding process but slows the operation of abcde quite a bit:
LOWDISK=y

# Specify the method to use to retrieve the track information,
# the alternative is to specify 'musicbrainz':
CDDBMETHOD=cddb

# With the demise of freedb (thanks for the years of service!)
# we move to an alternative:
CDDBURL="http://gnudb.gnudb.org/~cddb/cddb.cgi"

# Make a local cache of cddb entries and then volunteer to use 
# these entries when and if they match the cd:
CDDBCOPYLOCAL="y"
CDDBLOCALDIR="$HOME/.cddb"
CDDBLOCALRECURSIVE="y"
CDDBUSELOCAL="y"

OGGENCODERSYNTAX=oggenc                 # Specify encoder for Ogg Vorbis
MP3ENCODERSYNTAX=lame                   # Specify encoder for MP3
FLACENCODERSYNTAX=flac                  # Specify encoder for FLAC
MPCENCODERSYNTAX=mpcenc                 # Specify encoder for Musepack
AACENCODERSYNTAX=fdkaac                 # Specify encoder for AAC
OPUSENCODERSYNTAX=opusenc               # Specify encoder for Opus
WVENCODERSYNTAX=wavpack                 # Specify encoder for Wavpack
APENCODERSYNTAX=mac                     # Specify encoder for Monkey's Audio
TTAENCODERSYNTAX=tta                    # Specify encoder for True Audio
MP2ENCODERSYNTAX=twolame                # Specify encoder for MP2
MKAENCODERSYNTAX=ffmpeg                 # Specify encoder for MKA (AC3 via FFmpeg)

OGGENC=oggenc                           # Path to Ogg Vorbis encoder
LAME=lame                               # Path to MP3 encoder
FLAC=flac                               # Path to FLAC encoder
MPCENC=mpcenc                           # Path to Musepack encoder
FDKAAC=fdkaac                           # Path to the AAC encoder
OPUSENC=opusenc                         # Path to Opus encoder
WVENC=wavpack                           # Path to WavPack encoder
APENC=mac                               # Path to Monkey's Audio encoder
TTA=tta                                 # Path to True Audio encoder
TWOLAME=twolame                         # Path to MP2 encoder
FFMPEG=ffmpeg                           # Path to FFmpeg (AC3 via FFmpeg)

OGGENCOPTS='-q 6'                       # Options for Ogg Vorbis
LAMEOPTS='-V 2'                         # Options for MP3 
FLACOPTS='-s -e -V -8'                  # Options for FLAC
MPCENCOPTS='--extreme'                  # Options for Musepack
FDKAACENCOPTS='-p 2 -m 5 -a 1'          # Options for fdkaac
OPUSENCOPTS="--vbr --bitrate 128"       # Options for Opus
WVENCOPTS="-hx3"                        # Options for WavPack
APENCOPTS="-c4000"                      # Options for Monkey's Audio
TTAENCOPTS=""                           # Options for True Audio
TWOLAMENCOPTS="--bitrate 320"           # Options for MP2
FFMPEGENCOPTS="-c:a ac3 -b:a 448k"      # Options for MKA (AC3 via FFmpeg)

OUTPUTTYPE="ogg,mp3,flac,mpc,m4a,opus,wv,ape,tta,mp2,mka"  # Encode to 11 formats!

# The cd ripping program to use. There are a few choices here: cdda2wav,
# dagrab, cddafs (Mac OS X only) and flac. New to abcde 2.7 is 'libcdio'.
CDROMREADERSYNTAX=cdparanoia            
                                     
# Give the location of the ripping program and pass any extra options,
# if using libcdio set 'CD_PARANOIA=cd-paranoia'.
CDPARANOIA=cdparanoia  
CDPARANOIAOPTS="--never-skip=40"

# Give the location of the CD identification program:       
CDDISCID=cd-discid           
                               
# Give the base location here for the encoded music files.
OUTPUTDIR="$HOME/Music"               

# The default actions that abcde will take.
ACTIONS=cddb,playlist,read,encode,tag,move,clean

# Decide here how you want the tracks labelled for a standard 'single-artist',
# multi-track encode and also for a multi-track, 'various-artist' encode:
OUTPUTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/${ARTISTFILE}-${ALBUMFILE}/${TRACKNUM}.${TRACKFILE}'
VAOUTPUTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/Various-${ALBUMFILE}/${TRACKNUM}.${ARTISTFILE}-${TRACKFILE}'

# Decide here how you want the tracks labelled for a standard 'single-artist',
# single-track encode and also for a single-track 'various-artist' encode.
# (Create a single-track encode with 'abcde -1' from the commandline.)
ONETRACKOUTPUTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/${ARTISTFILE}-${ALBUMFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}'
VAONETRACKOUTPUTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/Various-${ALBUMFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}'

# Create playlists for single and various-artist encodes. I would suggest
# commenting these out for single-track encoding.
PLAYLISTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/${ARTISTFILE}-${ALBUMFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}.m3u'
VAPLAYLISTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/Various-${ALBUMFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}.m3u'

# This function takes out dots preceding the album name, and removes a grab
# bag of illegal characters. It allows spaces, if you do not wish spaces add
# in -e 's/ /_/g' after the first sed command.
mungefilename ()
{
  echo "$@" | sed -e 's/^\.*//' | tr -d ":><|*/\"'?[:cntrl:]"
}

MAXPROCS=2                                # Run a few encoders simultaneously
PADTRACKS=y                               # Makes tracks 01 02 not 1 2
EXTRAVERBOSE=2                            # Useful for debugging
COMMENT='abcde version 2.7.2'             # Place a comment...
EJECTCD=y                                 # Please eject cd when finished :-)
```

Keep in mind that this ~/.abcde.conf can also be used for a *single* audio codec rip and encode by using something like the following:

```
abcde -o mp3
```

This will utilise the 'mp3' section of the conf file only... How cool is the command line :)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look here also..

[A collection of abcde.conf files...](https://www.andrews-corner.org/abcde/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want start from a full list of configuration options and defaults, copy `/etc/abcde.conf` to `~/.abcde.conf` and edit it.

Putting only `OUTPUTTYPE="ogg,mp3,flac,mpc,m4a,opus,wv,ape,tta,mp2,mka"` into that file will provide multiple file type outputs without changing any other configuration options.